# How do I output the regression prediction from each tree in a Random Forest in Python scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there is a way to get the predictions from every tree in a random forest in addition to the combined prediction?  I would like to output all of the predictions in a list and not view the entire tree.  I know that I can get the leaf indices using the apply method, but I'm not sure how to use that to get the value from the leaf.

Edit:  Here's what I have so far from comments below.  It wasn't clear to me before that the trees in the estimators_ attribute could be called, but it seems that the predict method can be used on each tree using that attribute.  Is this the best way to do this, though?

```
numberTrees = 100
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=numberTrees)
clf.fit(X,Y)
for tree in range(numberTrees):
    print(clf.estimators_[tree].predict(val.irow(1)))
```

Comment: +1 – You can also do the same thing quite nicely with list comprehension: `per_tree_pred = [tree.predict(X) for tree in clf.estimators_]`

Comment: If you want to match the parallel jobs behavior of the model, just copy the source code for `predict` and leave off the last step where the predictions are averaged!

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that what you have up there is about the best you can do. As you noted, `predict()` returns the prediction for the whole RF, but not for its component trees. It can return a matrix, but that's only for the case where there are multiple targets being learned together. In that case it returns one prediction per target, it doesn't return predictions for each tree. You can get the individual tree predictions in R's random forest using `predict.all = True`, but sklearn doesn't have that. If you tried using `apply()`, you'd get a matrix of leaf indices, and then you'd still have to iterate over the trees to find out what the prediction for that tree/leaf combination was. So I think what you have is about as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems like something that anyone using the ensemble methods in scikit-learn would use, so I'm surprised that I haven't gotten more input from others.  My particular interest is seeing how RF can be used for predictions with 2 or more answers.  So, I'm plotting the prediction from each tree to see the distribution of results.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I don't know how you got the right answer by using `print(clf.estimators_[tree].predict(val.irow(1)))`. It gave me random numbers instead of the actual class. After reading the source code in SKlearn, I realized that we actually have to use `predict_proba()` instead of predict in the code and it gives you the class that the tree predicts according to the order in `clf.classes_`. For example:

```
tree_num = 2
tree_pred = clf.estimators_[tree_num].predict_proba(data_test)
print clf.classes_  #gives you the order of the classes
print tree_pred  #gives you an array of 0 with the predicted class as 1
>>> ['class1','class2','class3']
>>> [0, 1, 0]
```

You can also use cls.predict_proba() on your data and it gives you the probability of each class prediction by the accumulation of trees and releases you from the pain of going through each tree yourself:

```
x = clf.predict_proba(data_test) # assume data_test has two instances
print rfc.classes_
print x
>>> ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']
>>> [[0.12 ,  0.02,  0.86], # probabilities for the first instance
     [0.35 ,  0.01,  0.64]]  # for the second instance
```

Comment: Hi, Maybe a follow up question, is there also something that takes like the standard deviation/variance of all these trees? Ie let me know how reliable my prediction is?

Comment: @HME Follow up questions better be asked in separate posts to help others who might have the same problem finding them. A short answer to your question: one of the methods in sklearn random forest regressor is "score" that given the data and the true classes gives the coefficient of determination. Check it out here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score

Answer (score 0):

What I have done recently is modify sklearn source code to get it. Inside sklearn package
**sklearn.ensemble.Randomforestregressor**

There is a function that if you add print you will see the individual results of each tree. You could change this to be a return and get the individual results of each tree.

```py
def _accumulate_prediction(predict, X, out, lock):
    """
    This is a utility function for joblib's Parallel.

    It can't go locally in ForestClassifier or ForestRegressor, because joblib
    complains that it cannot pickle it when placed there.
    """
    prediction = predict(X, check_input=False)
    print(prediction)
    with lock:
        if len(out) == 1:
            out[0] += prediction
        else:
            for i in range(len(out)):
                out[i] += prediction[i]
```

This is a bit more sophisticated since you have to modify the sklearn source code

Comment: Is it possible to define a class and inherit Randomforestregressor as parent class. Then overwrite this function in child class??

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure what you exactly want, but there are other some methods in [Scikit-learns Random Forest Regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) that will most likely return what you want, specifically the [predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.predict) method! This method returns an array of the predicted values. What you were referring to about getting the mean is the [score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) method, which simply uses the `predict` method to return the coefficient of the R squared determinant.

Comment: Random Forest is an ensemble method that averages the predictions from many decision trees.  The predict method gives the average of the predictions from all of the trees, but I would like to see all of the predictions for a given input.  E.g., if I use 10 estimators in the Random Forest regressor, I would like to see the predictions from the 10 trees instead of the average that is given by the predict method.

Comment: @chunky I know what a random forest is, and that is odd, because given the documentation, it seems that `predict` would give an array of the predictions from each tree, which is what you are asking for. I have not used random forests in a couple months and cannot test this out for you right now, but based on the documentation, you are describing score, not predict. Score outputs the average, predict outputs an array of all predictions based on all of the trees

Comment: Score returns the R^2 value which is not what I want at all.  Per the documentation, predict returns 'The predicted regression target of an input sample is computed as the **mean predicted regression targets of the trees in the forest**'.  It returns the average of all of the trees predictions.  I don't want the average of the predictions, but the predictions themselves.

Comment: Ahh.. I think I'm getting close now.  I was using predict on the Random Forest to get the average prediction on the trees in the forest.  I just needed to use the predict method on each tree.  It looks something like this.`clf = RandomForestRegressor(); clf.fit(X,Y); for tree in range(numberTrees): print(clf.estimators_[tree].predict(val.irow(1)))`  I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, though.

Comment: I mean that does it, but I still don't understand how you are actually getting a value from predict when it returns an array of the predictions on each tree...so theoretically predict returns an array of what you are doing in your for loop. Maybe you are not using the most up to date version of Scikit learn.

Comment: The predict method returns **one** prediction for each input that you give it.  You need the for loop to get the prediction from each tree.  You're getting hung up on the docs telling you that it returns an array of predictions.  The array give you the predictions for separate input. E.g., I can pass an array of five inputs that I need predictions for, and the predict method will return an array of length 5 containing the predictions for each separate input.  You need the above code to get predictions from all trees for 1 input.  I guess it's one of those things that you need to run to see.

Comment: understood. I am getting hung up on the docs because I cannot test this out right now, so all I have are the docs

Comment: Did you ever solve it because this is exactly what I want to do for RandomForestClassifier